# A class with extra field

Tags: object-oriented

Let's say I have an animal class...with fields of name, height and weight.
I want to create a bird class which is an animal, but it has also, say, wing size.
How can I do that?

My general idea is creating the animal class, and the bird class which inherits animal, and has additional field ...but then different kinds of birds would inherit that class.

**My Questions:**

- Is my solution an appropriate OO approach to this type of problem?
- Is there a known design pattern for handling data modeling problems of this type?

Comment: Focus on using OO to solve implementation problems as they arise -- usually this means either eliminating code duplication or eliminating unwanted dependencies.  With experience, you will be able to foresee implementation problems and arrive at a good solution more quickly.

Comment: whatever **wing** is, it sure has to somehow "override"/"inherit" particular **fin**. "A wing is a type of fin..." ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wing))

Answer (score 2):

You would only add members to your `Bird` class that are common to all birds.  If you want to add a member called `Fly()`, you must either create a `FlyingBird` class that inherits from Bird, or inherit from an `IFlying` interface and implement the `Fly()` method on it.

```
public class Bird : Animal
{
    public float WingSize;
    ...
}

public Interface IFlyable
{
    void Fly()
    void Land();
}

public class FlyingBird : Animal, IFlyable
{
    public void Fly()
    {
         // Flap wings
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not need the fly member. maybe a getter setter for the wingSize. Oh and thank you!

Comment: Don't forget, some birds that cannot fly still have wings. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you add such a field to a derived class, just like you described. All birds have wings.

It is useful to contemplate how you will use this property.  People new to OO, and especially oldsters who programmed way before the early OO days, may want to write code like (not in any particular language):

```
for all Animals a in someListOfAnimals:
   print a.name, " has weight of ", a.weight
   if a is a Bird,
       print " and a wingspan of ", a.wingsize
```

but that is seriously wrong in OO design.  You must always try to think at the right level of abstraction.  The right way will be something more like

```
for all Animals a in someListOfAnimals:
   print a.descripion()
```

and define a virtual "description()" method for Animal and for Bird.   The Bird.description() method will, of course, print out the wingsize along with the usual stuff.  Animal.description() doesn't mention wingsize.

In case someday you run across some odd species of bird without wings, no need to make a tangled hierarchy of classes.  The real world is full of exceptions.  Just set wing size to zero, or some bogus value, or add a boolean  haswings member.